# Silverlight can't download clientaccesspolice.xml without running Fiddler

Tags: c#, silverlight, cross-domain, webclient, fiddler

My project consists of 2 parts Silverlight and WindowsForms. 
WindowsForm returns data at localhost:8081 or another port. 
Data can easily see through the browser by typing the address, with the parameters on all computers.

If Silverlight is enabled on the local server everything works fine, the problems start when you run it on an external server.

On my computer everything works fine, but on some computers, an error is returned "Async_ExceptionOccurred".

Following the network turned out that Silverlight can't get clinetaccesspolice.xml, request has been sent but nothing happens, no error is returned. Of course directly in the browser can open the file.

After turned  Fiddler bug disappears on some computers.

It follows that clinetaccesspolice and cross-domain set correctly. Something is blocking communication between Silverlight from external domain and localhost.

Comment: Is it fetching that file over a secure transport?

Comment: Everything works on HTTP, not on HTTPS

Comment: possible duplicate of [Silverlight Requests, Failures & Fiddler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971828/silverlight-requests-failures-fiddler)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Maybe it's not too professional, but solves the problem.

Fiddler share its own engine for developers. Use it in the program used on PC. The engine will automatically change the proxy settings so the client does not need to know anything ;)

[Fiddler core](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore)

```
// Call Startup to tell FiddlerCore to begin listening on the specified port,
// and optionally register as the system proxy and optionally decrypt HTTPS traffic.
Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(8877, true, true);

// Call Shutdown to tell FiddlerCore to stop listening on the specified port, and 
// unregister as the system proxy if attached.
Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Shutdown();
```